# When I save the docx file in python, data gets corrupted

Tags: python, python-docx

I am able to edit & save txt without problem but when I save the docx file, data gets corrupted. Like the image here: [image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlEdq.png) Any suggestions to save docx properly? Thanks.

```
    def save(self,MainWindow):
        if self.docURL == "" or self.docURL.split(".")[-1] == "txt":
            text = self.textEdit_3.toPlainText()
            file = open(self.docURL[:-4]+"_EDITED.txt","w+")
            file.write(text)
            file.close()
        elif self.docURL == "" or self.docURL.split(".")[-1] == "docx":
            text = self.textEdit_3.toPlainText()
            file = open(self.docURL[:-4] + "_EDITED.docx", "w+")
            file.write(text)
            file.close()
```

Comment: `docx` extension is not enough to make the file a Word (docx) file. Did you try to use `python-docx` package (https://pypi.org/project/python-docx/)? What you write is just plain txt file with `docx` extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.docx` files are much more than text - they are actually a collection of XML files with a very specific format. To read/write them easily, you need the [`python-docx`](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module. To adapt your code:

```
from docx import Document

...

elif self.docURL == "" or self.docURL.split(".")[-1] == "docx":
    text = self.textEdit_3.toPlainText()
    doc = Document()
    paragraph = doc.add_paragraph(text)
    doc.save(self.docURL[:-4] + "_EDITED.docx"
```

and you're all set. There is *much* more you can do regarding text formatting, inserting images and shapes, creating tables, etc., but this will get you going. I linked to the docs above.